Trying to call Azure Rest API with powershell Exception calling "AcquireAccessToken" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid tenant id provided
Trying to call an API via powershell whilst logged into Azure interactively using powershell. I hve written the code below, but I am getting the error after running
ConnectAzAccount first
ParentContainsErrorRecordException:
Line |
  23 |      $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.t …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "AcquireAccessToken" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid tenant id provided. You can locate your tenant id by following the instructions listed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/partner-center/find-ids-and-domain-names"

The powershell script is as follow
function Get-AzCachedAccessToken (){
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    if (-not (Get-Module Az.Accounts)){
        Import-Module Az.Accounts
    }

    $azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    $profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile)
    Write-Debug ("Getting access token for the tenant" + $currentAzureContext.Tenant.TenantId)
    Write-Verbose ("Tenant: {0}" -f  $currentAzureContext.Subscription.Name)

    $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.tenant.TenantId)
    $token.AccessToken
}

function Get-AzBearerToken()
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    ('Bearer {0}' -f (Get-AzCachedAccessToken))
}

#GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/$rg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apimService1/tenant/gitAccess?api-version=2024-05-01

